# Multi-dimentional array how to get the nested value without foreach loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I got output from one of the WordPress table cells. The following value is displayed.

```
$allcoinkey=get_option('_transient_mcw-custom-data');
    var_dump($allcoinkey);
```

and the output:

```
 [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["slug"]=>
    string(7) "bitcoin"
    ["keywords"]=>
    string(30) "بیتکوین,بیت کوین"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["slug"]=>
    string(8) "ethereum"
    ["keywords"]=>
    string(27) "اتریوم,اتاریوم"
  }
}
```

How do I access keyword values where `slug=bitcoin` **without** `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

i use this sample code:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```php
<?php
$allcoinkey = [
    [
        'slug' => 'bitcoin',
        'keywords' => 'بیتکوین,بیت کوین',
    ],
    [
        'slug' => 'ethereum',
        'keywords' => 'اتریوم,اتاریوم',
    ],
];
$bitcoinKeywords = current(array_filter($allcoinkey, static function (array $cryptoCurrency) {
    return $cryptoCurrency['slug'] === 'bitcoin';
}))['keywords'];

echo $bitcoinKeywords;
```